# PayPal API to pay via credit card

Tags: paypal

I need to allow users to pay via Credit Card on my site. I'm trying to find suitable API option but can't find it. I have implemented payment via PayPal so far, but now I need to allow users to pay via credit card without account on PayPal.

Anyone knows what specific payment type that is?

Comment: Please, show your appreciation and mark acceptable answers to previous questions you've asked. Thanks. :)

Comment: Better Answer Here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689640/paypal-express-checkout-pay-without-account

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way:

First, you'll need a **[Website Payments Pro](https://merchant.paypal.com/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant/wp_pro)** merchant account with PayPal. Then, become familiar with the [**DoDirectPayment API**](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_DoDirectPayment), which will allow you to
 process transactions *on* your site with PayPal working in the background. Customers will be able to fill out their credit card information, etc., on your site without visiting PayPal directly.

*This also means that customers will not be required to have a PayPal account in order to make a transaction on your site.*

If you proceed this way, you will need SSL certificates, and are required to implement Express Checkout for customers who do not want to make their transaction on your site.

[Sample Code](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code) to get your feet wet. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. Where can I find that form to place on my website?

Comment: If I understand well, to test payment status and update in 'in the background' I need to use PayPal SandBox and as method I have to use Express Checkout ? I have ipn implemented for other type of transaction.

Comment: To test without going live, meaning without using real money, you can use PayPal's Sandbox environment. With sandbox, you can setup test accounts with fake amounts of money, and test your site with these test credentials. I'm not completely familiar with IPN, but it appears you would still need to execute both Express Checkout API (for PayPal users), and DoDirectPayment API (for non-PayPal users). Doesn't IPN notify you of events that trigger transactions? (Not necessarily execute operations that process transactions?)

Comment: By form, do you mean the form for the customer to fill out his billing/credit card information? You can generate your own HTML form, and ensure that you assign the form's resulting POST variables to the operation's required, corresponding name-value pair.

Comment: OK I managed to send MassPay to PayPal. Thanks. Now, I need to receive payment statuses from PP. Should I use IPN and Express Checkout method for it?

Comment: With IPN, you can be notified of events related to PayPal transactions, such as when payments are *pending, completed, or denied.* IPN is the way to go.

Comment: Too bad Paypal Payments Pro is only available in US country :(

Comment: Yes @ElsonSolano is right! Paypal Payments Pro works only in US, UK and Canada, the rest of the world can.. :D It's quite frustrating!