# Paypal Express Checkout - Pay without account

Tags: php, paypal

In my PayPal express checkout there's no way for customer to pay whithout PayPal account.

I've seen this post:

[PayPal: express checkout pay without account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689640/paypal-express-checkout-pay-without-account)

I've added &SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole&LANDINGPAGE=Billing to the expressChechout call, which is fine but it just opens the tab "New Customer".

Also PayPal Account Optional is On.

I have a PayPal Buisness account.

Is there a solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you check this as well ? you must have 'PayPal Account Optional' set to 'On' with the 'Website Preferences' section of your PayPal account.

Comment: Yes. just checked that out. Is set to on.

Comment: Be sure the email address is confirmed on the merchant account

Comment: Email is confirmed. still no changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you pass SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole, LANDINGPAGE=Billing and USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE=CreditCard in SetExpressCheckout API call, some of your customers will still be forced to open a PayPal account in order to pay with a credit card and they will see the "New Customer" tab.

This is based on customer's country of origin, so you can't do anything about that. In order to pay with a credit card you will need to select a country. When you change the country in the payment form you'll see that some people can just pay with a credit card without a PayPal account, and some will see the "New Customer" tab and being forced to open a PayPal account.

Answer (score 0):

There's a new parameter you need to include to handle this better.  Make sure the API version you're setting is 109.0 or higher, and then add USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE=CreditCard

Comment: Current version is 109.0. I've added the parameter but it stills opens the new customer tab.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your raw request?