# Credit Card Options in Paypal Express Checkout

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have setup the express checkout process integration in asp.net mvc. When user is redirected to paypal website after submission, there is only option to login using paypal or sign up new account. There is no option to pay using credit card ?

Am i using right API for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Express Checkout is for PayPal accountholder payments; originally you would pair this with some other product for credit card payments (such as collecting the card information on your site and calling PayPal DirectPay or some other card processing partner).

PayPal also has several somewhat-similar products that collect the card information on their site (so you don't have to) and do that as well as accountholder payments; these vary in whether they end up giving you access to the credit card information (more flexible, but means you have to safely handle the card information and meet industry regulations, including vetting) or you do not ever see the card, just the money (simpler). This is often called some form of "guest checkout."

And eventually PayPal did add a guest checkout option to Express Checkout called "Account Optional." So you can use Express Checkout and get a guest checkout experience. See this link:

[PayPal: express checkout pay without account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689640/paypal-express-checkout-pay-without-account)

So in short you can get this from EC if you configure things for it, although some other PayPal products might be a better fit depending upon your particular requirements.

Comment: Ok i figure it out, Credit card option is displayed for verified business account not for developer account. I want to know if i can hide the option for paypal login so user can only see the credit card option to pay.

Comment: Not with Express Checkout. That's not what the Express Checkout product is for. Frankly, that's not what PayPal is for, although they do have a couple of products that will allow you to do this if you want to. Since they provide a product they believe (correctly, IMO) is superior to direct credit card entry they believe it is better for both you and your buyers if you offer that option to your buyers.