# PayPal: express checkout pay without account , Not possible?

Tags: java, paypal, express-checkout

I have used the answers given in

[Paypal express checkout without account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689640/paypal-express-checkout-pay-without-account)

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28622525/credit-card-options-in-paypal-express-checkout?lq=1)

But even after adding LOCALECODE=us,SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole,LANDINGPAGE=Billing and setting AccountOptional to ON in website preferences,

I can able to set the checkout option without paypal account?

I am using a Paypal Business account, country - US.

Any idea?

Comment: What API Version are you sending in the request?

Comment: I would recommend ditching localecode, and add USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE=CreditCard

Comment: @AndrewAngell am using version 109.0

Comment: Did you try adding the parameter I mentioned?

Comment: @AndrewAngell Yes. It worked. Thank you